# Absolute/relative position attempt forces scrollbar to top of page

Tags: css

So I've been trying to get the hang of absolute and relative positioning. There are lots of tutorials and questions asked on this subject, and I have done my best to understand them. I am mostly good with it except this one point. I am creating a page where there are smaller thumbnail images that the user has the option to click on and expand the image. To do this, I am just using a hidden layer that contains the larger image that only appears when the user clicks on the image. I've gotten this part to work just fine. My problem is that if I am scrolled down on the page some and click the image, the scroll bar jumps to the top of the page before revealing the hidden div. I was under the impression that it only did this when you just used absolute positioning (relative to the window, not a div anchor). It appears where I want it to, but it jumps to the top of the screen. I've looked around and can't find a solution to my exact problem. Thanks in advance.

HTML/CSS Code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="enlarge2()">
<img src="http://www.myadverket.com/images/smallemail.png" style="border: 2px solid  
#E0E0E0">
</a>
<div style="position: relative">
<div id="image2" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 200px; width: 100%;  
height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; visibility: hidden">
....Content....
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function enlarge2() {
var image = document.getElementById("image2");
image.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the difference

```
<script>
    function test(){
        //onclick event stuff 
    }
</script>
<div style="height:3000px">a</div>
<a href="#" onclick="test(); return false;"> link1 <!-- will work as expected --> </a> 
<a href="#" onclick="test();">link2 <!--will scrollup --> </a>
<a id="cometome" href="#" onclick="test(); return false;"> link3 <!-- will not scroll --> </a>
<div style="height:3000px">b</div>
<a href="#cometome">scroll to link3!</a>
<a href="#">scroll to top!</a>
```

Comment: so after fire and bubbleing up the onclick event, the DOM trys to solve the `href="#"` command in your anchor. even it's not existing somewhere it causes the page to scoll up to the first anchor, because `=#` is a scrollto command to anchor with `id=[??]`

Comment: Genius. Thanks, adding the return false solved the problem and I think I understand why now.

Comment: yes, because its the same as `document.getElementById('cometome').addEventListener('onclick',function test(){/*do stuff here*/}, false);`